# How do I determine programmatically whether a font support specific Language?

Tags: fonts

I want to use the fonts that located in my computer and I would like to take into consideration only those which support french. How do I determine programmatically whether a font support specific Language?
os: mac
language: prefered python but can handle whatever

Comment: Which programming language are you using? What platform, Windows, Unix etc

Comment: preferably python and i am using mac . I have tried https://github.com/davelab6/pyfontaine but it doesnt seems to give  good results